# Add a set of Namespaces to every Class file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Often when working in VS2010 I find that I have a list of namespaces I want in *all files*.  For example

```
using Common.Logging;
```

Is there a way I can configure this, preferably at a project or solution level?

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't something built-in to do that.  You can edit the Class.zip file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Code\1033 to change the usings in the default class created by "Add Class".

You might want to consider using a custom snippet instead of "add class" if you want something project/solution specific.

Comment: Perhaps a custom class template?

Comment: Using templates is a bit tedious; (add, navigate to template, type name, etc.) but, that's another option.